# A dataclass as a key to a defaultdict: KeyError

Tags: python, defaultdict, python-dataclasses

Please explain and maybe help how to fix `defaultdict` with a frozen `dataclass` key.

Example:

```
"""Reproduce KeyError: defaultdict with dataclass keys"""

import collections
import dataclasses
import unittest


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class ReservationCoverageKey:
    """AWS RDS Reservation dimensions"""

    database_engine: str
    instance_family: str
    region: str


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Main test cases"""

    def test_dict_with_dataclass_keys(self):
        """Test normal dict with dataclass key"""
        result = {}
        key = ReservationCoverageKey(
            database_engine="PostgreSQL",
            instance_family="db.t3",
            region="eu-west-1",
        )
        result[key] = 0
        result[key] += 1
        result[key] += 2
        self.assertEqual(result[key], 3)

    def test_defaultdict_with_dataclass_keys(self):
        """Test defaultdict with dataclass key"""
        result = collections.defaultdict(default_factory=int)
        key = ReservationCoverageKey(
            database_engine="PostgreSQL",
            instance_family="db.t3",
            region="eu-west-1",
        )
        result[key] += 1
        result[key] += 2
        self.assertEqual(result[key], 3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Reproduce:

```
$ python3 defaultdict_keyerror_reproduce.py 
E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_defaultdict_with_dataclass_keys (__main__.TestCase)
Test defaultdict with dataclass key
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/tmp/sscce/defaultdict_keyerror_reproduce.py", line 41, in test_defaultdict_with_dataclass_keys
    result[key] += 1
KeyError: ReservationCoverageKey(database_engine='PostgreSQL', instance_family='db.t3', region='eu-west-1')

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

The testcase with `dict` works, but not with the `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`collections.defaultdict(default_factory=int)` creates a default dict with no default value type, and one value (the type `int` at the key `"default_factory"`) because `default_factory` can only be passed as positional argument. Any keyword arguments are considered key-value pairs for the dictionary:

`defaultdict(None, {'default_factory': int})`

You need to do `collections.defaultdict(int)`, which produces `defaultdict(int, {})`

Comment: Since there is [agreed-upon syntax for positional-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) (that is now usable for user-space functions, too!), and the `help(collections.defaultdict)` doesn't use it or say anything about `default_factory` being positional-only (although it makes sense that it would be), I think there's a documentation bug to report.

Comment: @Karl What Python version? `help(defaultdict)` gives me *"`defaultdict(default_factory=None, /, [...])`"*, and the [*documentation*](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) says *"The __first argument__ provides the initial value for the `default_factory` attribute"*…

Comment: 3.8.5. It tells me `defaultdict(default_factory[, ...]) --> dict with default factory`. Apparently 3.8 got maintained all the way to 3.8.12 (so far), so it may well have been fixed for that minor.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to use `result = collections.defaultdict(default_factory=int)` instead of `result = collections.defaultdict(int)`?

If you change it that way, it will pass the test. I don't know why it does not accept as you declared.

I think it is not accepting default key as keyword argument.

Example:

```py
import collections

result = collections.defaultdict(default_factory=int)
result2 = collections.defaultdict(int)
result3 = collections.defaultdict()

print(result)
print(result2)
print(result3)

#output:
> defaultdict(None, {'default_factory': <class 'int'>})
> defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {})
> defaultdict(None, {})
```

When you pass `default_factory` property, it does not assign it as default key because it is  positional argument. So, you are getting KeyError.

Comment: The `default_factory` argument can only be passed as *positional argument*, and all keyword arguments are going to be treated the same as if you passed them to `dict`; i.e. `default_factory=int` will become a key-value pair in the created dict. It's odd to me that it raises a `KeyError`; I'd rather expect the key to default to `None`, and for that to cause a `TypeError` with `+= 1`… but there's probably some implementation reason for that.

Comment: Thank you for clarification!